# Simultaneous assignment in Go

Tags: variable-assignment, go, simultaneous

I'm learning Go and can't understand one thing, why creators of this language do support simultaneous assignment? It is very easy to make mistakes like a, b = a, b and not a, b = b, a, as I would want, thanks in advance for any good explanations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> It is very easy to make mistakes like a, b = a, b and not a, b = b, a,

If simultaneous assignment were not available then you would have to do something else instead. An alternative approach might look something like this:

```
tmp = a
a = b
b = tmp
```

That's much easier to get wrong.

Answer (score 8):

How else would you get access to the second, third, fourth, … return value of a function?

Comment: can You explain please? what does that mean?

Comment: @rookie: If a function returns two values, but you can only assign one of them, how do you get access to the second?